# Can grant money be spent on travel to program committee meetings?

Tags: peer-review, conference, funding, travel, program-committee

Many research conferences hold an in-person program committee meeting for all of the members of the program committee, where the PC members make the final decisions about which papers to accept or reject.  (At least, that's how it tends to work in computer science; I don't know about other fields.)

Can program committee members use federal grants to pay for their travel costs to attend a program committee meeting, for conferences where they are on the program committee?  Generally speaking, what funding sources do professors tend to use, to pay for travel to these meetings?

Comment: Surely this is a question for your funding agency?

Comment: I would expect the conference to pay this.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub: In CS (in my experience), conferences do not pay for this.

Comment: The grant proposal financial section should have addressed travel expenses clearly, and the sponsor should have made the decision before the award. Otherwise, you should assume the answer is "no." My proposals always included travel funds for a reasonable (small) number of PC meetings.

Answer (score 3):

For each grant, or type of grant, there are rules specifying what it can be used for. You should follow these rules and, unless you ask us about a specific funding program or agency, it's impossible to give more specific advice.

Comment: And we can't give binding advise. you'd have to ask for a final answer from the founding agency in case of doubt.